# Accessibility inspector or test tool for .NET custom control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, accessibility

After developing a .NET custom control I want to make it accessibility conformal. However, I can't find any tool that I can use to test if my implementation is working correctly. Which tools exist (preferably free) for this task, like an inspector or other validation tool?

Note: this goes beyond setting AccessibleName etc. I need to fully implemented the MSAA stuff (e.g. as described in [Coded UI Test Extension for 3rd party Windows Forms controls–How to?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2011/10/28/coded-ui-test-extension-for-3rd-party-windows-forms-controls-how-to.aspx)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools available for testing of MSAA and/or UI Automation support in an application:

1. This page lists several options: [Testing Assistive Technology ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971312.aspx#tools_that_aid_testing)
2. Visual UI Automation Verify (also from Microsoft)
3. MSAA Checker (also from Microsoft, probably an older tool)

Comment: Honestly, I would throw #1 out the door, and use NVDA instead. MS built in tools are the bottom of the barrel type things. #3 is still valid and/or the Inspect32 app if you install VS or Win7 (probably 8 too) SDK.

Comment: Narrator is indeed not a good tool but Inspect (as mentioned in #1) is probably the best testing tool for MSAA and UI Automation. There are many screen readers (like NVDA) and they can be used for general tests. But when it comes to show details about an accessible object they don't help at all.

Comment: Would love to see a source for this. Never heard this before.